# jQuery Fancybox Ajax Dimension

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I know how to set dimension width and height on iframe and inline, but i have search for 2 hours now and looking thrue the doc but i cant figure out how to set the dimension to width: 50% and height: 50%

What do you guys say?

Answer (score 1):

```
'width': '50%',
'height': '50%'
```

for fancybox v1.3.x, also set

```
'autoDimensions': false
```

for fancybox v2.x set

```
autoSize: false
```

Comment: Didn't know I had to disable something to be able to set dimensions. Thanks! :)